# setTimeout function executing code without any delay . Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, sleep

Can anyone explain why this is happening. I have created a function in JS and trying to call it after 60 seconds using setTimeout function. But it runs right away after the page loads. Why is this happening and setTimeout  is not delaying the function code? Below is the code.

```
<script>

function first()
{

document.getElementById('addProductText').style.color="#32A067";

}
setTimeout(first(),60000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your call to the function without the brackets `()`:

```
setTimeout(first, 6000);
```

This way you are referencing to the function, and not calling it immediately.

Working example:

```js
function first() {
  document.getElementById('addProductText').style.color = "#32A067";
}
setTimeout(first, 6000);
```

```html
<div id="addProductText">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: thanks Tamas. Got It :)

Answer (score 1):

You should only pass the `name of the function` without calling it:

```js
function first(){
     console.log("Hello")
}
setTimeout(first, 60000);
```

Comment: You actually don't have to give the name of a function, you have another alternative that could also provide a function operating multiple instructions before calling the target function. See https://repl.it/repls/BelovedShallowBusinesssoftware/

Comment: What is important to do in order to prevent premature calls is that you give the reference of a function, whether it is the target function or an anonymous one.